# Как сделать типизацию для ключей объекта, которые приняты как аргументы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, типы

Допустим у меня есть объект с темой:

```
const theme: Theme = {
 primary: {
  main: "",
  other: "",
 },
 secondary: {
  black: "",
  white: "",
 }
}

interface PrimaryColors {
 main: string
 other: string
}

interface SecondaryColors {
 black: string
 white: string
}

interface Theme {
 primary: PrimaryColors
 secondary: SecondaryColors
}
```

Мне нужно принять значения для группы цвета `(primary | secondary)` и значения для самого цвета:

```
type FooProps = {
 colorGroup: keyof Theme
 color: keyof (PrimaryColors | SecondaryColors)
}

const foo = ({ colorGroup, color }: FooProps) => ({
 color: theme[colorGroup][color]
})
```

При передаче аргумента color в функцию foo typescript выдает ошибку:
*TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.*

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае проблема заключается в union типе `PrimaryColors | SecondaryColors`. У типов `PrimaryColors` и `SecondaryColors` нет одинаковых свойств, поэтому при попытке взять `keyof` - получается `never`.

Более того, сам подход не совсем корректный, так как нет связи поля `colorGroup` и поля `color`, то есть может быть вариант, когда группа указана `PrimaryColors`, а цвет из `SecondaryColors`.

Вместо этого можно вообще отказаться от типа, и использовать сразу [generic функцию](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

Для этого нужно:

1. указать, что generic параметр может быть только из ключей `Theme`: `T extends keyof Theme`
2. задать два параметра

   1. `colorGroup` с типом `T`
   2. `color`, с типом, `keyof Theme[T]` - в него войдут только ключи из соответствующего поля

В итоге это может выглядеть так:

```
function foo<T extends keyof Theme>(colorGroup: T, color: keyof Theme[T]) {
  return {
    color: theme[colorGroup][color]
  };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAtogXDAKk1MC8MA3gFAwAOATgJbICGFAnhiTDHVWBgERcA0pMEAkQVufUgF9+MCIlBgAJvSZEBAIwA2tYAGsx0mAHd4VKOhg9pE4teIczFAGbbEMAArU6jAMIgNICghVNloODGhqMABzUiEkURkoSJjbexFnYFcAZTlwJR8-AKCWTW09ROTSY1NzCI4U4jswBwzXbBRXFkoaZQwPHoL-QNJZeXyVHLHlXyGIG0bHAFcwYCgqcBhHEBAAHkwYRAAPM0UgnUQGEEcsHEQAPgAKUCGAcQoQRbIMTF4YZ4CMOdLtd2qgANqYAC6AEpgjAKIgoIsKGA4ax-glhOCMW8PmRIWCMZCBBIANzzYgAN3oMFo+E22weAHJul4GEzfkz2GAmdCqTS1PStiBmazlByYEzSrpefyKH8hYymaM8uLOdKdLLqfKFIqRcrcoo1ZLubygA)